# Return data from a JSON string into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have an array in JSON format:

```
    "[    
        {        
            \"acrescimo\": null,        
            \"tipo\": \"A\",        
            \"nome\": \"TABELA PRIME\",        
            \"ultima_alteracao\": \"2016-05-25 17:32:55\",        
            \"excluido\": false,        
            \"id\": 3801,        
            \"desconto\": null    
        },    
        {        
            \"acrescimo\": null,        
            \"tipo\": \"A\",        
            \"nome\": \"TABELA SPCAP-SPINT-SUL DISTR\",        
            \"ultima_alteracao\": \"2016-05-25 17:33:41\",        
            \"excluido\": false,        
            \"id\": 3803,        
            \"desconto\": null    
        }
   ...
```

I need to consume one Json in my class:

```
public class GetPrecoBO
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        ...
        public DateTime ultima_alteracao { get; set; }
    }
```

I searched the forum but did not find something to help me in particular.
How do I return the array data in my class?

Comment: Usually, you'd look at finding a means to convert from the JSON string to an Array of Dictionaries, and then use those Dictionaries to construct your object. (But I am not a C# coder.)

Comment: Anyway, you should probably use the term deserialize to indicate what you want to do with the JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but are you saying you need to deserialize your JSON array into your C# object type? If so, Newtonsoft JSON.Net Nuget package is the way to go and can serialize and deserialize for you.

Comment: Exactly because after deserialize will do an insert in my database

Comment: Perfect, than this is they way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using Json.NET you could deserialize the object as an IEnumerable of the GetPrecoBO object.

```
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<GetPrecoBO>(<jsonString>);
```